# Date formatting issue - PHP

Tags: date-formatting, php

I have an array :

```
$multiple_dates[0] = 2013-06-09 00:00:00;
$multiple_dates[1] = 2014-06-13 12:23:00;
```

Here is my code :

```
$format = "d-m-Y h:m:s";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($multiple_dates); $i++) {
$date_display = date_format(date_create($multiple_dates[$i]), $format);
      $fdate = date_translate($format, $date_display);
      echo $fdate;
}
```

But output is : 
09-06-2013 12:06:00
13-06-2014 12:06:00
Time is not correct...Any idea ?

Comment: the format is incorrect, use `i` for minutes not `m`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because minutes fraction is `i`, not `m` (which is month)

So

```
$format = "Y-m-d H:i:s";
```

Answer (score 2):

Your format is invalid. Try with:

```
$format = "d-m-Y h:i:s";
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be "i" like this

```
$format = "d-m-Y h:i:s";
```

edit like this you can get it

Answer (score 1):

Correct format is

```
$format = "d-m-Y H:i:s";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code --

```
<?php

$mydate = '2014-06-13 12:23:00';

$format = "d-m-Y h:i:s";
echo $date_display = date_format(date_create($mydate), $format);
```

Answer (score 0):

go for `$timestamp = strtotime("09-06-2013 12:06:00")` and set on  date('d-m-Y h:m:s', $timestamp);

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($multiple_dates); $i++) {
      $timestamp = strtotime($multiple_dates[$i]));
      $fdate=date('d-m-Y h:m:s', $timestamp);
      echo $fdate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). E.g.:

```
foreach ($multiple_dates as $date) {
  echo date($format, strtotime($date));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tryin this one is easier....

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($multiple_dates); $i++) {
echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s',strtotime($multiple_dates[$i]));
}
```

i would prefer this